# HTML5 FileWriter InvalidStateError

Tags: javascript, html, file

I'm using a `canvas` element to tile a number of `video` elements together in real time, which works fine. I'm also trying to grab the `canvas` data and write it to a file periodically, so I can encode a video from the file of raw frames when the `video` elements have finished playing.

I've got a function called on a timer interval every 40ms (giving 25fps) that roughly looks as follows (there's too much code to paste in its entirety):

```
function saveFrame() {

  // code to copy from video elements to my canvas...
  // ...

  // Get the canvas image data and write it to a file
  var imgData = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0,
                                           canvasElement.width,
                                           canvasElement.height);
  var b = new Blob([imgData], {type: 'application/octet-binary'});

  // Write the blob to a file I previously opened
  // fileWriter is a FileWriter that I obtained and saved previously
  fileWriter.write(b);
}

setInterval(function() {
              saveFrame();
            }, 40);
```

Every time I hit the `fileWriter.write(blob)` statement I get the following error:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: An operation that depends on state cached
>   in an interface object was made but the state had changed since it was
>   read from disk.

Is this a timing issue? Can't the file writer API support writing every 40ms?

Comment: I ended up buffering my images and writing them every 500ms. It works without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#widl-FileWriter-write-void-Blob-data) of method write:

> If readyState is WRITING, throw an InvalidStateError and terminate
>   this series of steps.

So you get `InvalidStateError` error because your `fileWriter` still write previous data.

Try to use `writeend` event and `setTimeout`:

```
function saveFrame() {
    var imgData = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0,
        canvasElement.width,
        canvasElement.height);
    var b = new Blob([imgData], {
        type: 'application/octet-binary'
    });
    fileWriter.write(b);
}

fileWriter.writeend = function () {
    setTimeout(saveFrame, 40)
}

saveFrame();
```